# Connecting VS 2015 to Xamarin Android Player

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

Please I have been battling with this for like 2 days now, 
pls I am having issues installing connecting my VS 2015 to Xamarin android player.
I have installed

1. VS 2015
2. List item
3. Xamarin Android Player
4. Enabled Virtualization in my BIOS (windows 10)
5. Installed Android Studio
6. Downloaded all the devices I need for debugging in my Xamarin Player.
7. Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.20

I don't know what else to do sir.
it keeps telling me '**Failed to initialized device Nexux 4 (Jelly Bean)**'

Comment: are you running Visual Studio and xamarin android player as admin ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I wansn't running them as an admin but just did and got the same error

'Failed to initialized device Nexux 4 (Jelly Bean)'

Comment: Do you have 32 or 64 bit version of XAP? Try them both, cannot think of anything else ...

Comment: I think I installed 64 bit. I will uninstall and try out the 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to resolve the similar error :

- Delete the `c:\ProgramData\XamarinAndroidPlayer` folder, before reinstalling.
- Edit the `installeddevices.json` files and replace the content with `{'machines':[]}` to avoid re-installation and to clear all the devices listed.
- You'd probably also want to clear out the device vdi folders too.

---

Solution by [*@SunnyOkoroAwa*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2623765/sunny-okoro-awa) after a small discussion.

- After the installation of the files I listed above.
- Navigate to `Network Connections` in `Control Panel`.
- Right click on `Virtual Box Host-Only Network`.
- Select `Properties`.
- Check the option `VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridge Networking Driver`.
- Reconnect the network.

Comment: I observed that when I uninstalled the 64 bit version, I seem not to find the folder path 'c:\ProgramData\XamarinAndroidPlayer' and even any json file.

Comment: @SunnyOkoroAwa, Don't know very well in that case. My problem is with `installeddevices.json`. The second step helped me.

Comment: let me finish the process first, I will keep you posted it. I have installed XAP, reinstalling VM VirtualBox at the moment.

Comment: I have uninstalled both and setup files and reinstalled but still yet, have same problem.

Comment: @SunnyOkoroAwa : Did you check your log file. Refer :  https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1730025-where-to-report-issues-with-the-android-player-preview

Comment: This link worked for me.

I had to CHECK Virtual NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver for it to come up.
Thanks @Vaikesh.

Comment: @SunnyOkoroAwa : Post your complete workaround. And how you solve your problem. So it will be helpful to others.

Comment: After the installation of the files I listed above,
I had to go to My 'Network Connections' in my control panel, found the Connection named 
'Virtual Box Host-Only Network', right clicked it and went to the properties and CHECKED the option 'VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridge Networking Driver' and reconnected.

This fixed it for me.